# SSAS deploy only changes to dimension, query change but column name remain the same

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube

How do I changes the query for an existing dimension and deploy with out having it wipe the cube partitions.

Details

Cube: 2 measure group
Measure 1 - Distinct customer
Measure 2 - counts and counts

Partitions : Based on time dimension - every 15 days is one partition for both measure.

History: from 6/1/2014 todate

Dimensions: 8

Problem: Need to update the query for one dimension, there is no changes to the key.

Roadblock: 
I have over 500GB of data in the partitions and I cannot even my mistake wipe out the partitions while deploying the changes to the dimension.

What I tried:

I made the changes and built the package and opened deployment wizard
selected Retain in every page, created script, opened script updated password and ran it on test DB.

```
The changes to the dimension was not deployed.
```

How do I changes the query for an existing dimension and deploy with out having it wipe the cube partitions.

Edit:

If I change the msprop:QueryDefinition=" in the data source views xmla, will it work?